# Python SSL Socket dies after some time

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, ssl

I wrote a small python server extending the `HTTPServer` and `BaseHTTPRequestHandler`. Additionally, I'm using the standard python ssl library to wrap my sockets. The server exposes one socket to an internal network where requests arrive regularly and one socket to the public.

Now I encountered the strange problem that after a seemingly random amount of time, the public socket "dies". This means it will discard any data sent to it without a reaction, no further SSL handshake is possible and every connection attempt to it never returns.

To cope with the problem, I wrote a script that is triggered by cron and uses unix `timeout` and `curl` to recognize the dead state and restart the server. However, of course I'd like to find the cause of this behavior.

I would already be happy if somebody could point me into a direction or tell me where I could do additional logging. From what I can tell, the socket dies usually some hours in magnitude of 1-10 after the last connection, but also sometimes survives a whole day without any requests. More then a week can pass without any problem or it can die like three times a day. Usually, there are at least some few connections per day, at peaks there are some every few seconds.

Some exeptions do happen which originate from broken SSL connections I think, but none of those can be linked to the socket dying. I'm 97% sure this isn't a problem of my code, I do extensive checking and logging (and some reasonable thinking beforehand, I hope) and as already mentioned, there are regular successfull connections processed on the private socket which means the server is not dead as whole. It should be worth mentioning the server is multithreaded using the python `ThreadingMixIn`, but there is no deadlock either since the code handling the private connection uses the same resources as the public one. I am aware that the server is exposed to the internet so I also conducted some penetration testing of which nothing could take the server down this way.

I would be extremely happy if somebody got an idea!
Thanks in advance!